# What's wrong with my regex?

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression

```
#!/bin/sh

REGEX="^[2][0-2]:[0-5][0-9]$"
TIME="21:30"

if [ $TIME = $REGEX ]; then
    echo "Worked"
else
    echo "Did not work"
fi
```

I guess it has something to do with the : but as far as I'm concerned, this is just a regular sign that needs no escape sequence.

Comment: search internet for `bash if conditional regex`

Comment: See also [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also go for the `case` statement:

```
REGEX="[2][0-2]:[0-5][0-9]"; # Note no placeholders like ^ and $ here
TIME="21:30"
case $TIME in
   $REGEX ) echo "Worked" ;; # Note no double quotes around $REGEX for allowing the wildcard matching to happen
        * ) echo "Did not work" ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple `=` is wrong for regexp comparison. You have to use `=~`, and you'll also have to use a doubled bracket:

```
if [[ $TIME =~ $REGEX ]]; then
  ...
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420994/bash-regex-match-string

Comment: and ensure you're using bash and not a "sh" that doesn't support `[[`

Comment: May I ask how to do it on sh?

Comment: @Strict For `sh` you may want to take a look at the `case`-based solution posted.